# Find $m^3$ if $m=\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{3}}} + \sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt\frac{a-1}{3}}$

Tags: proof-writing, radicals, cubics, symmetric-polynomials, nested-radicals

Please help me solve this question in a easy way:

> $$
> \sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{3}}} + \sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt\frac{a-1}{3}} = m
> $$
>
> Find $m^3$.

(The answer is $8$.)

I tried solving the problem by substituting $x = (a-1/3)^{1/2}$ then used the identity $(a+b)^3 = a^3 + b^3 +3ab(a+b)$ this formed a cubic polynomial. But then I could not proceed. I was unable to solve ab. So please help in any way possible.

Comment: Please look up Mathjax to help format your question. Also, what have you tried so far?

Comment: I have edited his question to more readable form - would be nice if somebody accepted the edit.

Comment: Welcome to Math.SE! The community here prefers/expects questions to include something of what the asker knows about a problem. (*What have you tried? Where did  you get stuck?* etc) This information helps answerers tailor their responses to best serve you, without wasting time (theirs or yours) explaining things you already know or using techniques beyond your skill level. (It also helps convince people that you aren't simply trying to get them to do your homework for you.) As comments are easily overlooked, [edit the question](https://math.stackexchange.com/posts/3602031/edit) to add details.

Comment: @polaris inc. I solved your problem. If you want to see my solution, show please your attempts.

Comment: @Michael Rozenberg  I tried solving the problem by substituting x = (a-1/3)^1/2 then used the identity (a+b)^3 = a^3 +  b^3 +3ab(a+b)  this formed a cubic polynomial. But then I could not proceed. I was unable to solve ab. So please help in any way possible.

Answer (score 2):

The domain gives $a\geq1$.

For $a=1$ we obtain $m=2$ and $m^3=8$.

Let $a>1$.

Thus, since $$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a^2-bc)=\frac{1}{2}(a+b+c)\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2,$$ we see that $$a^3+b^3+c^3=3abc,$$ when $$a+b+c=0$$ or $$\sum_{cyc}(a-b)^2=0.$$
The last is possible for $a=b=c$.

But for $a>1$ we see that 
$$
\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{3}}}\neq\sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt\frac{a-1}{3}},$$ which says 
$$\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{3}}}+\sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt\frac{a-1}{3}}=m$$  it's
$$\left(\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{3}}}\right)^3+\left(\sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt\frac{a-1}{3}}\right)^3-m^3+$$
$$+3m\sqrt[3]{a + \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt{\frac{a-1}{3}}}\cdot\sqrt[3]{a - \frac{a+8}{3}\sqrt\frac{a-1}{3}}=0$$ or
$$2a-m^3+3m\sqrt[3]{a^2-\frac{(a+8)^2(a-1)}{27}}=0$$ or
$$2a-m^3+m\sqrt[3]{-a^3+12a^2-48a+64}=0$$ or
$$2a-m^3+m(4-a)=0$$ or
$$m^3-4m+(m-2)a=0$$ or
$$(m-2)(m^2+2m+a)=0$$ or $$m=2,$$ which gives $$m^3=8$$